# Word template error in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, ms-word

I have asp.net mvc application. I use MS Word template (*.dot) for generation Word document. When I execute my application I have error: "The message filter indicated that the application is busy". I found microsoft solution http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247028/en, but this is don't help me. What's wrong?

Comment: Word automation is not designed to be used in a multithreaded web application such as ASP.NET. Only on desktop applications. So you have a serious architectural design problem.

Comment: but what can I do that my application can work? I have about 10 diffrent templates, but only one of them don't work. In debug mode application works well, when I publish one to my IIS6 I have a troubles.

Comment: as I already said: don't use Word in a web application. I don't like repeating myself.